# "this" context in a function

Tags: javascript, data-structures

In the following code, I am unable to understand few things about `this`

```
function Stack() {
  let items = [];
  push = function(element){
   items.push(element);
 };

 this.pop = function(){
  return items.pop(); // removes and returns the element.
 };
}
let stk= new Stack();
stk.push(); // 1 
stk.pop(); //  no error
```

1. throws `stk.push` is not a function. why ? why lack of `this` is blocking the push method.
2. why it has to be `new Stack()`, why cannot it be `let stk= Stack()` to recognize methods inside the function?

since I am instantiating the Stack function, irrespective of whether the methods are declared with `this` or not , the **stk** var should be able to access functions, isn't it?

Comment: `push` cannot be accessed from outside of the `Stack` function simply because this is not how the language works... you **should** first learn the language and only then ask questions probably :)

Comment: [understanding-prototypes-in-javascript](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see two examples:

```
push = function() { /*...*/ }
```

And

```
var push = function() { /*...*/ }
```

In the first one `push` is a global variable.
So we do not define anything like `Stack.push` it's `push`.
So wen you do:

```
push();
```

It's executed and fails of course!

In the second one the variable is scoped locally that means it can be used only inside `Stack` function.

So in that case the push is undefined anywhere outside Stack.

No `push` and `Stack.push` nor `stk.push` is defined.

Now let's view other options:

```
this.push = function() { /*...*/ }
```

This defines field `push` of the current object.

Let's clarify that:

```
let Stack = function() {
     this.push = function() { console.log("Hello!"); }
     console.log(this);
};
Stack();
```

So what we get is:

> Window {frames: Window, postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, …}

Wait what? That means that the context (`this`) of function is `Window` object.
So in that case (if we work inside browser) we defined **again** the global
variable `push`!

```
let Stack = function() {
     this.push = function() { console.log("Hello!"); }
};
Stack();
push();
```

Outputs

> Hello!

So now to the rescue comes the `new` keyword.
Basically the Mozilla docs say:

> When the code new Foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
>   The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments, and with
>   this bound to the newly created object.
>   new Foo is equivalent to new Foo(),
>   i.e. if no argument list is specified,
>   Foo is called without arguments.
>
> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead.
>
> (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

That's it!
The new keyword binds `this` to `newly created object`.

So when we execute

```
new Stack()
```

The `this` keyword refers to the object we create! Thats why when we assign

```
this.push = /* Something */
```

It can be understood like the following code:

```
// Create new stack object
var stack = /* This is done by the 'new' keyword */ 

// Run our code
stack.push = /* Something */
```

So bassically that's it! Hope it helps you :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new  

The source I used :))

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object and **this** refers to the specific instance of an object.

If you have a function within a function without the **this**, it is local to the function.

With the **this** the inner function becomes a method of the object and may be called to perform some action.